# What steps to take when there is extremely low values of error or extremely high values of error?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

So I am training an ANN for classification between 3 classes. The ANN has an input layer, one hidden layer and a 3 node output layer.

The problem I am facing is that the output being produced by the 3 output nodes are so close to 1 (for the first few iterations at least and so i am assuming the problem propagates to future outputs as well) the weights are not being updated (or hardly updated) due to overflow (about `10^-11`). Now I can fix the overflow problem (but I don't think it is the culprit). I think such low values of error is the main culprit, and I cannot figure what is causing such low values of error.

What will cause the network to behave more interactively like I will be actually able to grasp the weight updates and not something in the order of `10^-11`?

Note: Data set contain values in the order of `10's` and the weights randomly initialized are in the order of `0 < w < 1`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the outputs of all the 3 output nodes are close to 1, then your error should be high. Please check your cost function.

Please try with different learning rates for parameter updates.